# How to play audio/video files in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, audio-streaming

I'm using flex 3.

I've successfully played video and audio files by using following libraries:

```
flash.media.Video
flash.media.Sound
```

Live docs [link](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Video_06.html).

But the limitations are as follow:

1. Video class can be used to play only flv file format.
2. To play mp3 files I must use audio file.

So can I play most of the famous audio/video files by using single method?

Well by checking the file type we can some how achieve it. Then I should create a component for that.

So can any one suggest me such ready-made components? or is there any other alternatives to play audio/video files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to play *any* video/audio formats in flash? (Almost) impossible. ActionScript libraries will not help you - ActionScript has not enough power to decompress video in realtime. Maybe this is possible with Alchemy, but I haven't seen codecs implemented this way... Usually, people are converting their content to FLV which is played by Flash player natively.

Comment: Okay may be we can play only flv files. but for mp3 files I'd still like to display waves. Is it possible? how?

Comment: Google "play mp3 flash", ten top results.